# Issues with rand() function

Tags: c++, c

I'm having some issues with my random-generated "snake pellet". I want the `*` to be used as the food for my snake. It's not generating inside the `char` array that I'm using as the board for the game. I'm not sure; I could be calling it wrong or using the function improperly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h> 
using namespace std;

char Map[11][22] =
{
  "---------------------",
  "|S              *   |",
  "|                   |",
  "|                   |",
  "|                   |",
  "|                   |",
  "|                   |",
  "|                   |",
  "|                   |",
  "|                   |",
  "---------------------"
};
int x = 1, y = 1;
bool GameRunning = true;
int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int pellet = rand();

  while (GameRunning == true)
  {
    for (int pellet = 0; pellet % Map[11][22]; pellet++)
    {
      cout << '*';
    }
    system("cls");
    for (int display = 0; display < 11; display++)
    {
      cout << Map[display] << endl;
    }
    system("pause>nul");

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
    {
      int y2 = y + 1;
      if (Map[y2][x] == ' ')
      {
        Map[y][x] = ' ';
        y++;
        Map[y][x] = 'S';
      }
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
    {
      int y2 = y - 1;
      if (Map[y2][x] == ' ')
      {
        Map[y][x] = ' ';
        y--;
        Map[y][x] = 'S';
      }
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    {
      int x2 = x+1;
      if (Map[y][x2] == ' ')
      {
        Map[y][x] = ' ';
        x++;
        Map[y][x] = 'S';
      }
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    {
      int x2 = x - 1;
      if (Map[y][x2] == ' ')
      {
        Map[y][x] = ' ';
        x--;
        Map[y][x] = 'S';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `pellet % Map[11][22]` to do, but it just goes out of bounds on your array. Clang gives me a warning about it, too: *warning: array index 22 is past the end of the array (which contains 22 elements)* (oddly enough, it doesn't do the same for the first dimension going out of bounds)

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`?

Comment: I thought it would cycle through the array and display the '*' did I not use it properly

Comment: you set pellet' from rand, then promptly overlayed the value in the for() statement

Comment: regarding this statement: 'for (int pellet = 0; pellet % Map[11][22]; pellet++)'  Map[11][22] is outside the bounds of the array.  the max Map is: 'Map[10][21]'  (because 'C' indexing starts at 0 and extends though size-1

Comment: when modifying 'x' and 'y' to effect snake movement.  those values need to be limited to the area of the map  I.E. [0][0] through [10][21]

Comment: oops, I just noticed the map has borders, so the valid range on the map is [1][20] through [9][20

Comment: pellet needs to be defined as int pellet[2]; so the pellet can be placed on other than the first row of the available map space.   the line: 'system("pause>nul");' will cause the program to hang there until 'some; key is pressed.  the next keystroke will be 'lost' as it is absorbed by 'pause'.  Suggest replacing that line with something like: nanosleep( 1000*1000);

Comment: sorry this is my 1st time posting to this site so im getting a little confused with whose talking about what haha.. but this is what I changed so far

Comment: `int main()
{
 Map[random_x_val][random_y_val] = '*'
 srand(time(NULL));
 int pellet = rand()%21;`

Comment: also the nanosleep function isnt working do I need a new header file for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite `pellet` in the for loop with 0 so it is always initialized with 0 instead of `rand()`.  Also, `rand()` produces some random number between 0 to at least 32767, so you need to mod it to get the range you want.  e.g. from 0-20 you would do `pellet = rand() % 21` or 4-16 you could do `pellet= (rand() % 13) + 4` (since 4-16 can be rewritten as range 0-12 plus 4).  Here is documentation for `rand()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

On a second note, do you really need a for loop?  And should it really be in the game loop?  It seems it would make more sense to set it once at the beginning.

you would want to set some random box in the map as the `'*'` at the beginning using something like `Map[random_x_val][random_y_val] = '*'` where `random_x_val` and `random_y_val` are valid ranges for your matrix.

Comment: I changed it to `for (int pellet = rand(); pellet % Map[11][22]; pellet++)` and now im getting a warning and now im getting a blank console

Comment: due to the map borders, the valid range is 1...20, not 0...20

Comment: I added an example above how to start a random number range at a number other that 0.

Comment: I added that to the beginning of my my main did you mean outside of main where I created the char array because its giving me errors

Comment: in the main, before you enter the `while (GameRunning == true)`.  If you put it in the while loop, it's going to set it every time the while loop does a loop.

Comment: ok thats where I put it and it doesnt seem to like it im getting red lines